# In GCP what values do I need to keep secret

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to cloud development so forgive me if this is a silly question but I am confused as to which values I need to be keeping secret and which ones I can make public / leave in my GitHub repository.

I am using GCP cloud run which authenticates a user via Oauth2 and then communicates with a database on GCP Firestore.  For all this I've accumulated a growing collection of IDs and am now a bit confused as to which I need to keeping secret and which ones are fine to be public. For example:

- Project name
- Project ID
- Project number
- Oauth Client ID
- Oauth service account ID
- Oauth service account email
- Oauth service account private_key (99% sure this needs to be secret :) )

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a public repository to share projects, keep all this info private. This is easy if you replace all this info in your code with ENV variables or key files (when is possible to do it) if you are using a private repository to develop with your team is still a good practice to keep the info as private as possible but you can have a little bit more of flexibility. But my advice is to never share any private info that can be used to identify or access your GCP products.

I also recommend you to follow the [Data loss Prevention](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data) best practices if you want to make your account more robust and secure